# Angular form with datepicker, problem with validators

Tags: angular, date, datepicker

I have to make a form on angular and only for the date input I use the Material librarie (to get the datepicker).

Here is how I declare my form :

```
this.editProfileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  lastname: [this._appState.user.lastName, Validators.required],
  firstname: [this._appState.user.firstName, Validators.required],
  email: [this._appState.user.email, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
  phone: [this._appState.user.phone.replace(/\s/g, ''), [Validators.pattern('[0-9]{10}')]],
  birthdate: [this._appState.user.birthDate, [Validators.required]],
  password: [''],
  new_password: [''],
  new_password_confirm: [''],
});
this.editProfileForm.setValidators([this.ageValidator]);
```

And the ageValidator :

```
public ageValidator(form: FormGroup): any {
const birthdate = new Date(form.controls.birthdate.value);
const min_date = new Date();
min_date.setFullYear(min_date.getFullYear() - 15);

return (birthdate.getTime() < min_date.getTime() ? null : {minAge: true});
```

}

And here is the HTML of the date input and his errors :

```
<div class="form-group">
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                    <input formControlName="birthdate" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && (f.birthdate.errors || editProfileForm.hasError('minAge')) }">
                    <mat-datepicker touchUi #picker></mat-datepicker>
                    <span (click)="picker.open()">test</span>
                </mat-form-field>
                <div *ngIf="submitted && (f.birthdate.errors || editProfileForm.hasError('minAge'))" class="invalid">
                    <div *ngIf="editProfileForm.hasError('minAge') && !f.birthdate.errors">{{ 'COMPONENTS.REGISTER.BIRTHDATE_ERROR_AGE' | translate }}</div>
                    <div *ngIf="f.birthdate.errors?.required">{{ 'COMPONENTS.REGISTER.FIELD_REQUIRED' | translate }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

My problem is strange and I can't understand why it's doing this.

If I enter a date with a format different than mm/dd/yyyy the input says that it's required (like if there is nothing inside). But when I use the datepicker it fill the input with a date in format dd/mm/yyyy and in this case I don't have error (why ??).

And if I enter a date with format mm/dd/yyyy (which is the one that doesn't throw an error) and then click to open the datepicker, the date is transformed to dd/mm/yyyy and the error still not appear.
I don't know if my explication is very clear.

Anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Ofc it depends on your locale, when you have the format as mm/dd/yyy you can't enter values such as 20/02/2019 as you would in dd/mm/yyy format, it should match your locale. As you have used angular material date picker, in order to change your locale you can follow the stack blitz example https://stackblitz.com/angular/lroqakengek

Comment: So my datepicker is in french locale (dd/mm/yyyy) and my input is in another locale ? (mm/dd/yyyy), how can I change the format of the input ? I'd like to keep the french format. And also, why the input say it's required if there is a value inside ? Even if the value is wrong